# Calculate and Concatenate in CSS variables

Tags: css, css-variables

Assume there is a `--size` variable and my purpose is to do something like this:

```
  .myElement {
    --size: 100;

    pading: var(--size / 2)px;
    margin: var(--size * 2)%;
    [anything]: var(--size) // calculate with --size and unit is px or % ...
  }
```

The code above is just assumed so how can I implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()) in your CSS properties to calculate pixel and percentage units of measurement with variables.

[image: box model]

```css
:root {
  --size: 100;
}

.myElement {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin: calc(var(--size) * .2%);
  padding: calc(var(--size) / 2 * 1px);
}

.myElement>span {
  background: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="myElement">
  <span>text</span>
</div>
```